# How to use iteration to insert HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have the following ugly hard code:

```
<div class="label">
    <p id="CO-0"></p>
    <p id="CO-1"></p>
    <p id="CO-2"></p>
    <p id="CO-3"></p>
</div>
```

How do I use iteration in JavaScript to insert the 0, 1, 2, and 3 `p` id's automatically?

This is my start:

```
for (i = 0; i< 3; i +=1){
    $('.label').html('<p id='+[i]+'></p>');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       $('.label').append( '<p id="CO-'+ i +'"></p>' );
 };
```

Comment: firstlu, he must defined variable, for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){

Answer (score 6):

While Dorin's answer is correct, for efficiency reasons, you should do the insert in one go, as DOM manipulations are relatively expensive.

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   html += '<p id="CO-'+ i +'"></p>';
};
$('div.label').html(html);
```

Answer (score 3):

It more elegant/efficient to do all your dom insertion at once:

```
var inhtml ="";
for (var i = 0; i< 3; i +=1){
    inhtml += '<p id=CO-'+i+'></p>';
}

$('.label').html(inhtml);
```

Comment: removed. I just copypasted them from example. also corrected the id to more with the html i question and more valid

Comment: Should be `i < 4` and while not wrong, I'm curious why you used `i+=1` instead of the more common `i++`

Comment: again too much inspired by the question. I'd normaly do `++` just because it's shorter.